# Flutter In App Purchases. Go to production

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-in-app-purchase

I am using the plugin in_app_purhcases in order to make purchases. I have tried it using the sandbox mode, so I am not charged for any purchase. The next step is to send the app to review and I am wondering how I can change it to production. I want to be sure that once I send the app to review, the sandbox mode cannot be used anymore.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

So In ios, if you are uploading an app in test flight it will always take as a testing environment.

For Production make sure you use a **distribution certificate** in ios when you upload with a distribution certificate it will take as a production environment.

Make sure you make a sandbox bool false in-app purchase plugin.